# Grails 2.3.4 Application Terminates During Startup After Updating to Release 2.5.6

Tags: upgrade, grails-2.3, grails-2.5

I have been given the task to update middleware Grails 2.3.4 system to Grails 2.5.6 in order to be Java 8 compatible. The original development team from 10 years ago has disbanded and the Grails corporate knowledge is gone. I am not a Grails developer but have followed the Grails instructions for updating from Grails V2.3 to V.2.5

There are no issues with compiling the updated code, and the WAR file build completes without errors. I place and expanding the WAR file on a test server. The working Grails 2.3.4 version opens 3 ports and continuously maintains 10 open connections to an Oracle Database Server, which I can see with 'lsof -i' command.

When I execute the Grails 2.5.6 build and continuously run 'lsof -i' I see that the 3 ports are open and for a moment the 10 Oracle database connections are established. Then a instant later the database connections are closed, but the 3 ports remain open.

Not sure what information is required so you kind folks can help me resolve my issue. Could not find anything on stackoverflow that would resolve my issue. The following is all I have from the system logs on starting this Grails 2.5.6 application from the point of failure

```
//-------------------------
2024-02-20 17:37:36,431 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener    - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
2024-02-20 17:37:36,746 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener    - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.List
    ... 5 more
2024-02-20 17:37:37,014 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.lifecycle.ShutdownOperations    - Error occurred running shutdown operation: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I followed the instructions from the official Grails 2.5.6 documentation. Updated the code base to remove 'Static Holder Classes', updated the applicationContext.xml etc.

The application successfully starts, opens ports, connects to Oracle and then just stops